# Company logo's embedding link?

Tags: php, image, embed

I would like to add a text box in my form where companies add their logo but only as a link. I don't want to store images in the server or in any folders, I just want them to have the ability to add thier logo to my page.

I have been looking for a code for this, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" name="imageurl" />
```

Later

```
<?php echo "<img src=\"".htmlspecialchars($_POST['imageurl'])."\" />"; ?>
```